# mov doesn't appear to be working

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, boot

I'm writing a bootloader for the x86 architecture. Up until now, I was just using 16-bit, and using BIOS calls for things like displaying characters, and reading the disk, etc., but now I want to enter 32-bit protected mode.

I decided to start off by not using the BIOS functions anymore, since they only work in 16-bit.

Since my bootloader will be loaded into `0x7c00` in memory (since the sector ends with `0xaa55`, *and* since I now want to be working in 32 bits, the first two lines in my `boot.asm` are:

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 32]
```

Now, to my understanding, the text video memory for the BIOS begins at `0xb8000`, so to display a character at the top left of the screen -- lets say, a white 'A' on a black background -- I would do this:

```
mov al, 'A'
mov ah, 0x0f ; white on black
mov [0xb8000], ax
```

To move the character with the correct attributes to the start of the video memory. I then emulated my operating system in bochs, but my character wasn't where I wanted to be. I couldn't see it.

I then thought that it might have something to do with my `[org 0x7c00]` directive, which to my understanding offsets any addresses I use. As a result of this, it would make sense that instead of moving `ax` to `0xb8000`, I instead move it to `0xb8000 - 0x7c00 = 0xb0400`. I replaced the code with:

```
mov al, 'A'
mov ah, 0x0f
mov [0xb0400], ax
```

But this had the same problem as the last attempt (the character wasn't on the screen, or at the correct memory location). I can't think of anything else to try, and searching the internet for any help doesn't seem to return anything of use.

Why isn't this working? How *do* I move the character `A` to this area of memory, if not like this?

Comment: It's not enough to just tell your compiler to emit 32 bit code, you must switch your CPU to protected mode, it won't run 32-bit code in real mode.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Just found [this page](https://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode) has an example.

Comment: By the way, once you start playing with CPU modes, why not [enable long mode](https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode) and unlock the full power of your CPU.